# How to use train_on_batch properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I am training my model using `model.train_on_batch()`. I dig into [Keras code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L23) how to use `train_ob_batch` properly. I notice before calling this function, Keras calls several routines, including `model._make_train_function()`.

But, I found many Github sources, they use `model.train_on_batch` without calling `_make_train_function()` first.

So, my question is whether calling `_make_train_function()` has to be called first before `train_on_batch`? I am using Keras 2.2.4 and Tensorflow 1.12.0

Thanks.

Comment: You can check a related comment here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6124#issuecomment-292752653

Comment: So, `_make_train_function()` is necessary to be called beforehand in multithread environtment? In other words, `_make_train_function()` exist only for multithread purpose?